# How I do save stars in Movie model?

Tags: django, django-models

## Wha I want to achive.

I want to save stars in Movie model when def average_stars() is used.
I want to put a number in stars and save it when the movie function is called like the code below. What should I do?

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, editable=False,
                          validators=[alphanumeric],max_length = 9999)
    stars = models.FloatField(
                    blank=False,
                    null=False,
                    default=0, 
                    validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(10.0)]
                     )
    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment_movie.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id)
    
    def average_stars(self):
        comments = self.get_comments()
        n_comments = comments.count()

        if n_comments:
            self.stars = sum([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
        else:
            self.stars = 0
        return self.stars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can access your related comments in a much easier way by using `self.relation_set.all()` etc. rather than importing and filtering by the other related object. Secondly, your code for getting the average is pythonic whereas you can use Django's ORM to aggregate the average stars rating, see below:

```py
def average_stars(self):
    avg = self.comment_set.aggregate(Avg('stars')).get('stars__avg')
    self.stars = avg
    salf.save()
    return avg or 0
```

This code also sets the stars value of the instance, saves it, and returns the average to wherever the function was called.

**Edit** - added `return avg or 0` as you want to put zero into your field rather than `None`, which `.get()` will return if nothing is found for whatever reason.